# Find the Taylor polynomial of degree n

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> -Find the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ for $f(x) = \sqrt{(1+x)}$, centered at $x = 0$.

-I know how to find taylor polynomial but when it comes to finding the $n^{th}$ term, I'm a little lost on finding what the pattern is.

We have $f^{'}(0) = \frac{1}{2}, f^{''}(0) = -\frac{1}{4}, f^{'''}(0) = \frac{3}{8}, f^{4}(0) = \frac{-3*5}{16}$ and $f^{n}(0) = \frac{-1^{n+1}}{2^n}*$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: You're right-- it's not an easy pattern-- it has to involve with binomial coefficients.

Comment: Write it as $(1+x)^{1/2}$. Keep differentiating. YOu should see a pattern in terms of binomial coefficients

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to apply the bionomial theorem.
$$(1+x)^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{a}{n}  x^n$$ and, if required, truncate where ever you need.

If $a=\frac 12$, remember that
$$\binom{a}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)! n!}$$ which then makes
$$\sqrt{1+x}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {x^n}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)!\,n!}$$